# A problem with compatibility of the script on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, com, handshake

This script works perfectly on Mac OS and Linux but when I try it on Windows it does not work.
When I try to try it on Windows, this error appears...
I imagine the problem from `switch_user(dev)`.
I tried it with her (dev) but I couldn't solve it.
Whereas when Check GPT is verified, it stops and the error occurs.

```
PS C:\Users\motc-pc\Desktop\amonet-karnak-\amonet\modules> python main.py
[2020-06-03 22:03:49.653199] Waiting for bootrom
[2020-06-03 22:03:59.339064] Found port = COM22
[2020-06-03 22:03:59.348800] Handshake

* * * If you have a short attached, remove it now * * *
* * * Press Enter to continue * * *


[2020-06-03 22:04:02.368897] Init crypto engine
[2020-06-03 22:04:02.422396] Disable caches
[2020-06-03 22:04:02.424535] Disable bootrom range checks
[2020-06-03 22:04:02.459386] Load payload from ../brom-payload/build/payload.bin = 0x4888 bytes
[2020-06-03 22:04:02.469524] Send payload
[2020-06-03 22:04:03.440416] Let's rock
[2020-06-03 22:04:03.442368] Wait for the payload to come online...
[2020-06-03 22:04:04.163004] all good
[2020-06-03 22:04:04.165239] Check GPT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 450, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 361, in main
    switch_user(dev)
  File "main.py", line 321, in switch_user
    block = dev.emmc_read(0)
  File "main.py", line 196, in emmc_read
    raise RuntimeError("read fail")
RuntimeError: read fail
```

This script is full.
As I said earlier when I trying it on Linux or MacOS it works normally without problems

```
import struct
import os
import sys
import time
from handshake import handshake
from load_payload import load_payload, UserInputThread
from logger import log
import struct
import glob
import serial
from logger import log

BAUD = 115200
TIMEOUT = 5


CRYPTO_BASE = 0x10210000 # for karnak


def serial_ports ():
    """ Lists available serial ports

        :raises EnvironmentError:
            On unsupported or unknown platforms
        :returns:
            A set containing the serial ports available on the system
    """

    if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
        ports = [ "COM{0:d}".format(i + 1) for i in range(256) ]
    elif sys.platform.startswith("linux"):
        ports = glob.glob("/dev/ttyACM*")
    elif sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
        ports = glob.glob("/dev/cu.usbmodem*")
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError("Unsupported platform")

    result = set()
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port, timeout=TIMEOUT)
            s.close()
            result.add(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass

    return result


def p32_be(x):
    return struct.pack(">I", x)


class Device:

    def __init__(self, port=None):
        self.dev = None
        if port:
            self.dev = serial.Serial(port, BAUD, timeout=TIMEOUT)

    def find_device(self,preloader=False):
        if self.dev:
            raise RuntimeError("Device already found")

        if preloader:
            log("Waiting for preloader")
        else:
            log("Waiting for bootrom")

        old = serial_ports()
        while True:
            new = serial_ports()

            # port added
            if new > old:
                port = (new - old).pop()
                break
            # port removed
            elif old > new:
                old = new

            time.sleep(0.25)

        log("Found port = {}".format(port))

        self.dev = serial.Serial(port, BAUD, timeout=TIMEOUT)

    def check(self, test, gold):
        if test != gold:
            raise RuntimeError("ERROR: Serial protocol mismatch")

    def check_int(self, test, gold):
        test = struct.unpack('>I', test)[0]
        self.check(test, gold)

    def _writeb(self, out_str):
        self.dev.write(out_str)
        return self.dev.read()

    def handshake(self):
        # look for start byte
        while True:
            c = self._writeb(b'\xa0')
            if c == b'\x5f':
                break
            self.dev.flushInput()

        # complete sequence
        self.check(self._writeb(b'\x0a'), b'\xf5')
        self.check(self._writeb(b'\x50'), b'\xaf')
        self.check(self._writeb(b'\x05'), b'\xfa')

    def handshake2(self, cmd='FACTFACT'):
        # look for start byte
        c = 0
        while c != b'Y':
            c = self.dev.read()
        log("Preloader ready, sending " + cmd)
        command = str.encode(cmd)
        self.dev.write(command)
        self.dev.flushInput()

    def read32(self, addr, size=1):
        result = []

        self.dev.write(b'\xd1')
        self.check(self.dev.read(1), b'\xd1') # echo cmd

        self.dev.write(struct.pack('>I', addr))
        self.check_int(self.dev.read(4), addr) # echo addr

        self.dev.write(struct.pack('>I', size))
        self.check_int(self.dev.read(4), size) # echo size

        self.check(self.dev.read(2), b'\x00\x00') # arg check

        for _ in range(size):
            data = struct.unpack('>I', self.dev.read(4))[0]
            result.append(data)

        self.check(self.dev.read(2), b'\x00\x00') # status

        # support scalar
        if len(result) == 1:
            return result[0]
        else:
            return result

    def write32(self, addr, words, status_check=True):
        # support scalar
        if not isinstance(words, list):
            words = [ words ]

        self.dev.write(b'\xd4')
        self.check(self.dev.read(1), b'\xd4') # echo cmd

        self.dev.write(struct.pack('>I', addr))
        self.check_int(self.dev.read(4), addr) # echo addr

        self.dev.write(struct.pack('>I', len(words)))
        self.check_int(self.dev.read(4), len(words)) # echo size

        self.check(self.dev.read(2), b'\x00\x01') # arg check

        for word in words:
            self.dev.write(struct.pack('>I', word))
            self.check_int(self.dev.read(4), word) # echo word

        if status_check:
            self.check(self.dev.read(2), b'\x00\x01') # status

    def run_ext_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.dev.write(b'\xC8')
        self.check(self.dev.read(1), b'\xC8') # echo cmd
        cmd = bytes([cmd])
        self.dev.write(cmd)
        self.check(self.dev.read(1), cmd)
        self.dev.read(1)
        self.dev.read(2)

    def wait_payload(self):
        data = self.dev.read(4)
        if data != b"\xB1\xB2\xB3\xB4":
            raise RuntimeError("received {} instead of expected pattern".format(data))

    def emmc_read(self, idx):
        # magic
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0xf00dd00d))
        # cmd
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0x1000))
        # block to read
        self.dev.write(p32_be(idx))

        data = self.dev.read(0x200)
        if len(data) != 0x200:
            raise RuntimeError("read fail")

        return data

    def emmc_write(self, idx, data):
        if len(data) != 0x200:
            raise RuntimeError("data must be 0x200 bytes")

        # magic
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0xf00dd00d))
        # cmd
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0x1001))
        # block to write
        self.dev.write(p32_be(idx))
        # data
        self.dev.write(data)

        code = self.dev.read(4)
        if code != b"\xd0\xd0\xd0\xd0":
            raise RuntimeError("device failure")

    def emmc_switch(self, part):
        # magic
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0xf00dd00d))
        # cmd
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0x1002))
        # partition
        self.dev.write(p32_be(part))

    def reboot(self):
        # magic
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0xf00dd00d))
        # cmd
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0x3000))

    def kick_watchdog(self):
        # magic
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0xf00dd00d))
        # cmd
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0x3001))

    def rpmb_read(self):
        # magic
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0xf00dd00d))
        # cmd
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0x2000))

        data = self.dev.read(0x100)
        if len(data) != 0x100:
            raise RuntimeError("read fail")

        return data

    def rpmb_write(self, data):
        if len(data) != 0x100:
            raise RuntimeError("data must be 0x100 bytes")

        # magic
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0xf00dd00d))
        # cmd
        self.dev.write(p32_be(0x2001))
        # data
        self.dev.write(data)





def switch_boot0(dev):
    dev.emmc_switch(1)
    block = dev.emmc_read(0)
    if block[0:9] != b"EMMC_BOOT" and block != b"\x00" * 0x200:
        dev.reboot()
        raise RuntimeError("what's wrong with your BOOT0?")
    dev.kick_watchdog()

def flash_data(dev, data, start_block, max_size=0):
    while len(data) % 0x200 != 0:
        data += b"\x00"

    if max_size and len(data) > max_size:
        raise RuntimeError("data too big to flash")

    blocks = len(data) // 0x200
    for x in range(blocks):
        print("[{} / {}]".format(x + 1, blocks), end='\r')
        dev.emmc_write(start_block + x, data[x * 0x200:(x + 1) * 0x200])
        if x % 10 == 0:
            dev.kick_watchdog()
    print("")

def flash_binary(dev, path, start_block, max_size=0):
    with open(path, "rb") as fin:
        data = fin.read()
    while len(data) % 0x200 != 0:
        data += b"\x00"

    flash_data(dev, data, start_block, max_size=0)

def dump_binary(dev, path, start_block, max_size=0):
    with open(path, "w+b") as fout:
        blocks = max_size // 0x200
        for x in range(blocks):
            print("[{} / {}]".format(x + 1, blocks), end='\r')
            fout.write(dev.emmc_read(start_block + x))
        if x % 10 == 0:
            dev.kick_watchdog()
    print("")

def force_fastboot(dev, gpt):
    switch_user(dev)
    block = list(dev.emmc_read(gpt["MISC"][0]))
    block[0:16] = "FASTBOOT_PLEASE\x00".encode("utf-8")
    dev.emmc_write(gpt["MISC"][0], bytes(block))
    block = dev.emmc_read(gpt["MISC"][0])

def force_recovery(dev, gpt):
    switch_user(dev)
    block = list(dev.emmc_read(gpt["MISC"][0]))
    block[0:16] = "boot-recovery\x00\x00\x00".encode("utf-8")
    dev.emmc_write(gpt["MISC"][0], bytes(block))
    block = dev.emmc_read(gpt["MISC"][0])

def switch_user(dev):
    dev.emmc_switch(0)
    block = dev.emmc_read(0)
    dev.kick_watchdog()

def parse_gpt(dev):
    data = dev.emmc_read(0x400 // 0x200) + dev.emmc_read(0x600 // 0x200) + dev.emmc_read(0x800 // 0x200) + dev.emmc_read(0xA00 // 0x200)
    num = len(data) // 0x80
    parts = dict()
    for x in range(num):
        part = data[x * 0x80:(x + 1) * 0x80]
        part_name = part[0x38:].decode("utf-16le").rstrip("\x00")
        part_start = struct.unpack("<Q", part[0x20:0x28])[0]
        part_end = struct.unpack("<Q", part[0x28:0x30])[0]
        parts[part_name] = (part_start, part_end - part_start + 1)
    return parts

def main():

    minimal = False


    dev = Device()
    dev.find_device()

    # 0.1) Handshake
    handshake(dev)

    # 0.2) Load brom payload
    load_payload(dev, "../brom-payload/build/payload.bin")
    dev.kick_watchdog()

    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "minimal":
        thread = UserInputThread(msg = "Running in minimal mode, assuming LK, TZ, LK-payload and TWRP to have already been flashed.\nIf this is correct (i.e. you used \"brick\" option in step 1) press enter, otherwise terminate with Ctrl+C")
        thread.start()
        while not thread.done:
            dev.kick_watchdog()
            time.sleep(1)
        minimal = True

    # 1) Sanity check GPT
    log("Check GPT")
    switch_user(dev)

    # 1.1) Parse gpt
    gpt = parse_gpt(dev)
    log("gpt_parsed = {}".format(gpt))
    if "lk" not in gpt or "tee1" not in gpt or "boot" not in gpt or "recovery" not in gpt:
        raise RuntimeError("bad gpt")

    # 2) Sanity check boot0
    log("Check boot0")
    switch_boot0(dev)

    # 3) Sanity check rpmb
    log("Check rpmb")
    rpmb = dev.rpmb_read()
    if rpmb[0:4] != b"AMZN":
        thread = UserInputThread(msg = "rpmb looks broken; if this is expected (i.e. you're retrying the exploit) press enter, otherwise terminate with Ctrl+C")
        thread.start()
        while not thread.done:
            dev.kick_watchdog()
            time.sleep(1)

    # Clear preloader so, we get into bootrom without shorting, should the script stall (we flash preloader as last step)
    # 4) Downgrade preloader
    log("Clear preloader header")
    switch_boot0(dev)
    flash_data(dev, b"EMMC_BOOT" + b"\x00" * ((0x200 * 8) - 9), 0)

    # 5) Zero out rpmb to enable downgrade
    log("Downgrade rpmb")
    dev.rpmb_write(b"\x00" * 0x100)
    log("Recheck rpmb")
    rpmb = dev.rpmb_read()
    if rpmb != b"\x00" * 0x100:
        dev.reboot()
        raise RuntimeError("downgrade failure, giving up")
    log("rpmb downgrade ok")
    dev.kick_watchdog()

    if not minimal:
        # 6) Install preloader
        log("Flash preloader")
        switch_boot0(dev)
        flash_binary(dev, "../bin/preloader.bin", 8)
        flash_binary(dev, "../bin/preloader.bin", 520)

        # 6) Install lk-payload
        log("Flash lk-payload")
        switch_boot0(dev)
        flash_binary(dev, "../lk-payload/build/payload.bin", 1024)

        # 7) Downgrade tz
        log("Flash tz")
        switch_user(dev)
        flash_binary(dev, "../bin/tz.img", gpt["tee1"][0], gpt["tee1"][1] * 0x200)

        # 8) Downgrade lk
        log("Flash lk")
        switch_user(dev)
        flash_binary(dev, "../bin/lk.bin", gpt["lk"][0], gpt["lk"][1] * 0x200)

    # 9) Flash microloader
    log("Inject microloader")
    switch_user(dev)
    boot_hdr1 = dev.emmc_read(gpt["boot"][0]) + dev.emmc_read(gpt["boot"][0] + 1)
    boot_hdr2 = dev.emmc_read(gpt["boot"][0] + 2) + dev.emmc_read(gpt["boot"][0] + 3)
    flash_binary(dev, "../bin/microloader.bin", gpt["boot"][0], 2 * 0x200)
    if boot_hdr2[0:8] != b"ANDROID!":
        flash_data(dev, boot_hdr1, gpt["boot"][0] + 2, 2 * 0x200)

    if not minimal:
        log("Force fastboot")
        force_fastboot(dev, gpt)
    else:
        log("Force recovery")
        force_recovery(dev, gpt)

    # 10) Downgrade preloader
    log("Flash preloader header")
    switch_boot0(dev)
    flash_binary(dev, "../bin/preloader.hdr0", 0, 4)
    flash_binary(dev, "../bin/preloader.hdr1", 4, 4)

    # Reboot (to fastboot or recovery)
    log("Reboot")
    dev.reboot()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Note the comment:`        # magic`

Comment: What's the difference between emmc_read and the dev.reads that have already happened?

Comment: @stark   Thanks for interesting and responding to my topic
This reading dev.emmc_read 
files GPT from  EMMC chip Phone , and then rewritten with modified files ... I imagine the problem from the port COM22 in the Linux system port = /dev/ttyACM0  It works without a problem

Comment: The code should print how many bytes it got.  Maybe it needs to be broken into multiple reads.

Comment: @stark ... I found the problem and it is from the port = /dev/ttyACM0
Is there a way to define this port on Windows? on windows port = COM22  ... I want to change from COM22 to  /dev/ttyACM0